# How to get the metadata of media content to a Notification while Casting using Chromecast?

Tags: google-cast

I have been looking at the sample code provided by Google for casting videos and am not able to figure out from where is the metadata being gotten from for the Notification. Below are the liks I am looking at.
Links: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/CastOptionsProvider.java 
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

I did some research and my assumption is that it gets the metadata from the TargetActivityClass which is ExpandedControlsActivity but I am not able to get it even there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When your app creates a MediaInfo to load on the receiver, you provide all the required metadata (title, image, etc) and that is how the framework handles the rest for you. Note that the framework also listens to the messages and status updates from the receiver so it stays up to date with what is playing on the receiver, hence can update the metadata for the notification, if necessary.